# jQuery: restrict keydown movement of object

Tags: jquery, keydown, pong

I am trying to work on a ping pong kind of game in jQuery and I was wondering how can I restrict the slider position inside a container.

I also need help with how to generate the ball/box and how to make it bounce on the side and top wall of the container.

I have managed to work on it but I am still struggling to retain the slider inside the container and struggling on the bouncing the ball around.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
[MyCodeSoFar](http://jsfiddle.net/dH4N7/3/)

Comment: I can see the plate but not the ball. I think your plate shouldn't go under 0 or over width...

Comment: @sinsedrix you can see the new version of the code here [jsfiddle.net/vchouhan/TPZtP/5/]. any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but your code is a bit messy for me. Whatever, I found this idea of a js pong like game funny and I adapted your code to do what you intended.

Just have a look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/4yHBg/)** and feel free to send me some feedback.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question! I tested your code and it works great! except for a few minor bugs. The ball does not bounce of the plate! it bounces of the wall! I am not sure about the speed of the ball, does it increase with time?

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a lot of general questions so I'll give you some general pointers. :)

> I am trying to work on a ping pong kind of game in jQuery and I was wondering how can I restrict the slider position inside a container?

To constrain the paddle, just check some offsets.

To determine if it's touching the left border, check its offset from the left. If it's `0`, ignore the <kbd>←</kbd> keydown.

To determine if it's touching the right border, take the left offset and add the width of the paddle. If it's equal to the width of the game area, ignore the <kbd>→</kbd> keydown.

> I also need help with how to generate the ball/box and how to make it bounce on the side and top wall of the container.

Since you are using elements and not `canvas`, you can generate a ball with CSS...

```
#ball {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

The key here is the `border-radius` being equal to the `width` and `height` of the ball.

To get the ball to bounce, have a `x` and `y` velocity that is incremented with your game timer. Flip the sign of these when the ball collides with either the paddle or the edges of the game areas. To make it more *Pong-like*, you can mess with how you modify the bounce when it hits certain regions of the paddle, for example, if it hits the far edge, it has a sharper angle when it reverses.

To determine if the ball has hit the edge of the game area, use a technique similar to what I described above.

To determine if your ball has impacted your paddle, use some collision detection code.
Check to see if the ball's Y offset is higher than the paddle's Y offset (I assume your paddle moves linearly on a horizontal track). Then, if that condition is met, see if the ball's X offset is within the range of the paddle's X offset and (`+`) the width of the paddle.

If your paddle and game area never change, it would be beneficial to cache these widths.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have managed to restrict the plate to the width of the container and got the ball moving down. but I cannot get the collision working. I have uploaded the updated version of the code to this URL [http://jsfiddle.net/vchouhan/TPZtP/3/]
I am going to give it another try and get the ball collision on the side of the walls and the plate to move in opposite direction?